# How are POST requests handled with Redux Form and Express?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form

When you’re using a normal HTML form and you submit a POST request, that request gets sent to the express post route like this:

```
app.post('/api/items', function(req, res) {
  // req from HTML form
});
```

But when you’re using Redux Forms and you’re making a POST request to an API, does that request then get passed through as the request in the post route the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Redux Form, the form is not submitted to like classic HTML forms. Instead, a callback (`onSubmit` by default) is triggered to submit the data.

Given the following form:

```js
reduxForm({
  form: "form",
  fields: ["foo", "bar"],
})(
  class MyForm extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" {...this.props.fields.foo} />
          <input type="text" {...this.props.fields.bar} />
          <button>{"Save"}</button>
        </form>
      )
    }
  }
)
```

You can post your form values to `/api/items` this way:

```js
<MyForm onSubmit={
  values => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch("/api/items", {method: "post", body: JSON.stringify(values)})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        if (res.hasOwnProperty("errors")) {
          reject(res.errors)
        } else {
          resolve(res.data)
        }
      })
  })
} />
```